# to use a library dll with LoadLibrary() method on C++

Tags: c++, winapi

Can I use LoadLibrary method for to import a data of type struct??
excuse me for my English. 
thanks.

Answer (score 8):

Let me assume some things that are left out in the question:

1. You have a dynamic library called **flubber.dll**
2. The library exports the function `bool GetFlubber(Flubber* flubber)`.
3. The function and the type `Flubber` (which just happens to be a `struct`!) are declared in a header file called **flubber.h**.

If those 3 conditions are met, then you can use `LoadLibrary` on **flubber.dll**, followed by `GetProcAddress` with `GetFlubber` as proc name, and finally you can declare a `Flubber` instance locally and pass it to `GetFlubber` via the retrieved proc address.

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean to put data in a dll, and use LoadLibrary and Getprocaddres to get a pointer to the data? That is possible, although it is more common to put functions in a dll, and let them return a pointer to the data.

Answer (score 2):

Hm ... That question was a bit hard to understand, I'm afraid.

In C++, a struct declaration is just that, a declaration. It does not generate something you can load at run-time, it's a pure compile-time construction that just tells the compiler how something is laid out in memory, the fields involved, their types and order, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you are using VC++ 2005.

MS now providing you [Delay Loading Dll's](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/151kt790.aspx).

The Visual C++ linker now supports the delayed loading of DLLs. This **relieves you** of the need to use the Windows SDK functions **LoadLibrary** and GetProcAddress to implement DLL delayed loading.

Steps to follow in order to setup the Delay Load.

Goto to Project->Properties->Linker->Input and then specify your Dll in 'Delay Loaded DLLs'

Comment: If he wants to load libraries dynamically based on versioning and availability, then LoadLibrary must still be used.

Answer (score 0):

As other responses have suggested it's hard to tell what's being asked here, but I'll throw in a response for another interpretation of the question.  I'm not sure if it's "officially supported", but you can have a DLL export a global variable and then dynamically access it via GetProcAddress.

For instance, if a library called foo.dll contains a global of type FOO named g_MyGlobal, then it can export the variable in foo.def.  Client code can then call:

```
MyPointer = GetProcAddress(..., "g_MyGlobal");
```

and get a "FOO *" pointer to the global.

...but with that said, if you find yourself needing to do this for something other than private testing purposes, you might want to re-think your design.  It would probably be much safer and cleaner to hide this global behind an exported function in the DLL.